Using React in existing Django Project
I have an existing Django project. Its a website that displays a map with leaflet.
Markers and everything is loaded dynamically from django.
Now I want to enhance that with React. In a sense that when you click a marker on the map, react will render based on marker_id the specific marker-details in a sidebar or something.
I am not sure how to do that. In the django template I have a onclick event to get the marker-details:
                    marker.uri = `/map/api/marker_details/?marker_id=${marker.marker_id}&marker_type=${marker.marker_type}`
                    marker.on('click', function (e) {

                        jQuery.get(this.uri);

                    });

Since this is all in django template and not in React, the result is probably not accessible via react to render the details. Do I have to implement the map with the marker and everything in React to then be able to render the details via API? What am I missing?

"I want to enhance that with React [...] Do I have to implement the map with the marker and everything in React" - Isn't that your stated goal?  What else are you trying to do in React besides build that UI?

Thank you for the response.
React should just render Marker_details in a sidebar popup/whatever based on what marker the user clicks on the map. The map and the markers etc. are already there. So it would just be a part of the website.

It sounds like you're just looking for this then?

@David Yeah I already checked that out. This part is clear to me. I give a element an id and then I can replace that element via React. So far so simple. What I dont get is how do I get the marker_details in there. Lets say I have 3 Marker, each with a onclick event to django backend to get their details. How would react know which marker_detail to render? I assume I would have to do the call via react frontend. If so how would I do that without rebuilding the whole page?

I ended up using  django-unicorn.
There you can call the backend from your template:
c.on('click', function (e) {
                            Unicorn.call('sidebar','get_details',this.marker_id,this.marker_type)
                        });

In the view you can make your query and give the result back to the template :
class SidebarView(UnicornView):
    name = ""

    def get_details(self,id_string,marker_type):
        print(id_string)

